# Use CSCOPE to search other type of files

Tags: cscope

Is it possible to include other type of file in the search result(e.g find the value of CFLAG in the makefile)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cscope is an excellent tool, but it really only understands C. (And boy, I wish it understood *more* C; I can't tell you how often I wished I could use Cscope to find a definition of a structure.)

Exuberant Ctags, on the other hand, understands a *lot* of languages (42 by my `ctags --list-languages`), one of which is `Make`.

Run `ctags -R .` to build a tags database of your source. (`ctags` has many command line options to configure how it works but this simple invocation works for me in a variety of projects.) Then you can run `vim -t CFLAGS` to jump right to the definition of `CFLAGS` in the `Makfile`. (It also enables the simple <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd> lookup in `vim` -- see `vim`'s `:help CTRL-]` for details.)

I usually use `cscope`, `ctags`, and `gid` all together in my own source navigating -- each tool does different enough things that most of my needs can be met with *one* of them -- the trick is figuring out which task is best suited to which tool.

Comment: This is an old answer, but thank you.  I didn't know about "Exuberant Ctags", but discovered it after seeing your answer.  It seems like a nice upgrade over the stock one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ruby gem that is cscope-like but supports ruby and golang. It is also extensible, so other languages can be added relatively easily.

http://rubygems.org/gems/starscope